Ascorbic acid disolved in carbonated water
I pour 1 gram of ascorbic acid (a white powder sold by the kilogram as food-grade thus hopefully dextrorotatory) at 25°C (it's hot in Paris) into a 1 liter bottle of carbonated water at 6°C (drinking-grade, or so tells the public fountain dispensing it, complete with analysis of the overall 420 milligram/liter of dissolved minerals).
I observe significant sparkling as the powder descends and dissolves. Nothing near Mentos/Coke-grade, but still it can't be missed.
Why? Is there some chemical reaction? Or is it only de-saturation of CO2 by some physical phenomena?

Update: I don't know the initial pH of the carbonated water. Before carbonation, it's reportedly about 8.7 on a yearly average, with regulatory limits [6.5, 9].
Links to Safety data and LD50 information on ascorbic acid. Seriously, avoid inhalation of the stuff or getting any in the eyes.
I recommend against consumption of the result of that or other experiment by human or other animal.

The powder probably acts as nucleation site for bubbles of $\ce{CO2}$ to form in the supersaturated carbonated water. Changing the pH turns some hydrogen carbonate into carbonic acid/$\ce{CO2(aq)}$ as well, but this is probably the smaller effect because most of the carbonate is in that form already when you mix pure water with carbon dioxide. What is the initial pH?

I don't know the initial pH of the carbonated water. Before carbonation, it's reportedly about 8.7 on a yearly average, with regulatory limits [6.5, 9].

This is an uncontrolled experiment. One gram is a lot of Vitamine C ~10X the MDR, also a lot of heat to add to the water. The CO2 water is probably slowly warming so most likely slightly supersaturated and subject to perturbation releasing CO2.  Ascorbic is essentially a lactone and not appreciably acidic so should not increase the acidity of carbonated water.

@jimchmst: on third though, you are right, and I added a paragraph to the Q.

If you added near any powder you would see sparkling of oversaturated $\ce{CO2}$ solution. Acids may just boost it if there is significant amount of $\ce{HCO3-}$, converting it to $\ce{CO2}$. pH 8.7 is very high, it seems there must be $\ce{HCO3-}$.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3958/does-citric-acid-react-with-carbonated-water

Almost anything can nucleate bubble evolution when pressure is suddenly released.

Shake a soda (pop, "Coke" [Atlantan], "tonic" [Bostonian]) bottle before opening.
Immerse the pop bottle in an ultrasonic bath.
Repeatedly scratch the inside of a glass filled a carbonated beverage with a glass rod.
Pour almost any powder, crystal, gravel, or other finely divided substances into freshly-poured pop.

You're dealing with a substance in a metastable (or downright unstable) state, read to "pop" off.
A similar effect is seen in supercooling and superheating, and is the reason cooks and chemists use boiling stones to decrease violent bumping.
